# pandas help in averaging uneven length groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I need some help from the Pandas clan leaders.
I have this dataset:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( { 
"phase" : ["PH1", "PH1", "PH1", "PH1", "PH1" , "PH1", "PH1"] , 
"sname" : ["CB01R", "CB01R", "CB01R", "CB01R", "CB01R", "CB01R", "CB01R"] ,
"patid" : ["PG01", "PG01","PG01", "PG02", "PG02", "PG02","PG02"] ,
"vbins" : [0., 50., 80., 0., 50., 80., 90.] ,
"vprob" : [100., 60., 0., 100., 60., 10., 0.] ,
} )
```

Where I basically can group the values as :

```
patid phase  sname  vbins  vprob
0  PG01   PH1  CB01R      0    100
1  PG01   PH1  CB01R     50     60
2  PG01   PH1  CB01R     80      0
```

and

```
patid phase  sname  vbins  vprob
3  PG02   PH1  CB01R      0    100
4  PG02   PH1  CB01R     50     60
5  PG02   PH1  CB01R     80     10
6  PG02   PH1  CB01R     90      0
```

The desired result is to average the vbins and vprob as below;

```
phase  sname  vbins  vprob
PH1  CB01R      0.5*(0+0)    0.5*(100+100)
               0.5*(50+50)     0.5*(60+60)
               0.5*(80+80)     0.5*(0+10)
               0.5*(NaN+90)     0.5*( NaN+0)
```

where the average is over the groups and NaN is used for unequal lengths. I tried `df1.groupby(['phase', 'sname', 'patid'])` to get the groups, then got stuck implementing a function to handle the desired averaging.

Comment: What should `NaN + 0` gives you? 0 or NaN?

Comment: that should give me a 0, sorry I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.groupby(
    [
        'phase', 'sname',
        df1.groupby('patid').cumcount()
    ]
)['vbins', 'vprob'].sum() / 2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should try pd.pivot_table, example:

```
pd.pivot_table(data=df, index=['phase','sname'], values=['vbins','vprob'], aggfunc='mean')
```

let me know if it works out

---

edit:

given the nature of your problem, you should before hand add another column, to make reference as to what will be groupedby at the pivot_table

Comment: I expect a vector for the mean rather than a single value so the output of your suggestion didn't give what I wanted. 
Out[4]: 
             vbins      vprob
phase sname                  
PH1   CB01R     50  47.142857